# How to properly update active record in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model having update method as

```
def udpate_something(params)
    update(id: params[:id],
           b: params[:b],
           c: params[:c],
           d: params[:d])
end
```

and in controller

```
def update
    Model.find(id: params[:id])
         .update_something(id: params[:id]
                           b: params[:b],
                           c: params[:c],
                           d: params[:d])
end
```

Is this the right way to update or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it should be **very rare** (i.e. virtually unheard of!) to update the `id` (primary key) of a record. This is a record's *identifier*; by changing this, you'll mess up any associations and potentially cause a conflict with another record's `id`.

Also, your `udpate_something` [SIC] method doesn't really achieve anything. It's a wrapper method that serves no purpose. Why not just do:

```
def update
  Model.find(id: params[:id])
       .update(b: params[:b],
               c: params[:c],
               d: params[:d])
end
```

Your controller method doesn't handle error messages, use strong parameters (!!) or perform any render/redirect action - but that's a separate story. There's no generic "right thing to do" across all controller actions; it really depends on what you're trying to achieve!

I'd suggest looking through some basic material such as the [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) to see how controllers are typically structured.